# Unexpected behaviour of Apache Commons CollectionUtils addAll(Collection collection, Object[] elements)

Tags: java, key-value, apache-commons-collection

**Brief description:**

Basically, inside my code i want to add a `List <String>` to every `<key>` inside a `ListValuedMap <String, List<String>>` as a `<value>`. I did some testing on the created ListValuedMap `spreadNormal` with

```
System.out.println(spreadNormal.keySet());
System.out.println(spreadNormal.values());
```

and it showed me, that the keys are inside the map (unsorted), but the corresponding values are empty. 
I am deleting the inserted `List <String>` after using `Collections.addAll(String, List<String>)` with `list.clear()` after each loop.

**I would have expected, that indeed a copy of these values stay in my `ListValuedMap` but my results are:**

```
[Agios Pharmaceuticals Inc., Vicor Corp., EDP Renov�veis S.A., Envista Holdings Corp., JENOPTIK AG,...]
[[], [], [], [], [], ...]
```

**My expected result is more like this:**

```
 [Agios Pharmaceuticals Inc., ...] =
[["US00847X1046, "30,60", "30,80", "0,65"], ....]
```

Can you provide some explanations on that? Is the default behaviour of the `Collections.addAll` method to copy the reference to an object, instead of the object itself?

The corresponding code section is highlighted with `// ++++++++++`

**Full code example (Eclipse):**

```
import java.io.*;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.commons.collections4.ListValuedMap;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.MultiSet;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.multimap.ArrayListValuedHashMap;


public class Webdata {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
        {
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            
            parseData();
            
            System.out.println(secondsElapsed(start)+" seconds processing time");
            
        };
            
    private static void parseData() throws IOException
        {
            
            List <String> subdirectories = new ArrayList<>();
            String chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            
            String errorMessage1 = "String formatting problem";
                String errorMessage2 = "String object non existent";
                
                for (int i=0; i< chars.length(); i++)
                {
                    subdirectories.add("https://www.tradegate.de/indizes.php?buchstabe="+chars.charAt(i));
                }
                
                    
                List <String> stockMetadata = new ArrayList<>();
                
                ListValuedMap <String, List<String>> nonError = new ArrayListValuedHashMap<>();
                ListValuedMap <String, List<String>> numFormatError = new ArrayListValuedHashMap<>();
                ListValuedMap <String, List<String>> nullPointerError = new ArrayListValuedHashMap<>();
                
                ListValuedMap <String, List<String>> spreadTooHigh = new ArrayListValuedHashMap<>();
                ListValuedMap <String, List<String>> spreadNormal = new ArrayListValuedHashMap<>();
                
                int cap1 = 44;
                int cap2 = 56;
        
                for (int suffix = 0; suffix <chars.length(); suffix++) 
                {   
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(subdirectories.get(suffix).toString()).get();
                Elements htmlTableRows = doc.getElementById("kursliste_abc").select("tr");
                
                htmlTableRows.forEach( tr-> 
                        {
                        String stockName    = tr.child(0).text();
                        String bid_price    = tr.child(1).text();
                        String ask_price    = tr.child(2).text();
                        String isin         = tr.child(0).selectFirst("a").absUrl("href").substring(cap1,cap2);
                        
//     +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

                        try 
                        {
                            if (calcSpread(bid_price, ask_price) < 5) 
                            {
                                Collections.addAll(stockMetadata, isin, bid_price, ask_price, calcSpread(bid_price, ask_price).toString());
                                spreadNormal.put(stockName,stockMetadata);  
        
                            }
                            
                            else if (calcSpread(bid_price, ask_price) > 5)
                            {
                                Collections.addAll(stockMetadata, isin, bid_price, ask_price, calcSpread(bid_price, ask_price).toString());
                                spreadTooHigh.put(stockName,stockMetadata); 
                                
                            }
                                stockMetadata.clear();
                                
                        }
                        catch (NumberFormatException e) 
                        {
                            Collections.addAll(stockMetadata, e.getMessage());
                            numFormatError.put(stockName, stockMetadata);
                            stockMetadata.clear();
                            
                        }
                        
                        catch (NullPointerException Ne) 
                        {
                            Collections.addAll(stockMetadata, Ne.getMessage());
                            nullPointerError.put(stockName, stockMetadata);
                            stockMetadata.clear();
                            
                        }   //end of try-catch

//     +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                        
                 });        //end of for-each loop htmlTableRows
            }               //end of JSOUP method
            
            
            System.out.println(spreadNormal.keySet());
            System.out.println(spreadNormal.values());
            
    }                   //end of parseData()
    
    
    public static Float calcSpread (String arg1, String arg2) 
    {
        try 
        {
            Float bid = Float.parseFloat(arg1.replace("," , "."));
            Float ask = Float.parseFloat(arg2.replace("," , "."));
            Float spread = ((ask-bid)/ask)*100;
            
            return spread;
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    
    public static Long secondsElapsed(Long start) {
        
        Long startTime = start;
        Long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Long timeDifference = endTime - startTime;
        
        return timeDifference / 1000;
    }
        
    
}  //end of class
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>TEST</groupId>
  <artifactId>TEST</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.3</version>
  </dependency>
  
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
    <version>4.4</version>
</dependency>
  
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>18</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with `Collections.addAll`.

I believe you expect all of your maps to be `ListValuedMap<String, String>` which is basically a `Map<String, List<String>>`. As such, your `ListValuedMap<String, List<String>>` is a `Map<String, List<List<String>>>`.

Just update each of your maps to be like below so each key is mapped to a `List<String>`:

```
ListValuedMap<String, String> nonError = new ArrayListValuedHashMap<>();
ListValuedMap<String, String> numFormatError = new ArrayListValuedHashMap<>();
ListValuedMap<String, String> nullPointerError = new ArrayListValuedHashMap<>();

ListValuedMap<String, String> spreadTooHigh = new ArrayListValuedHashMap<>();
ListValuedMap<String, String> spreadNormal = new ArrayListValuedHashMap<>();
```

And then, instead of using `ListValuedMap.put(K key, V value)` you have to use `ListValuedMap.putAll(K key, Iterable<? extends V> values)` like this:

```
spreadNormal.putAll(stockName, stockMetadata);
spreadTooHigh.putAll(stockName, stockMetadata);
numFormatError.putAll(stockName, stockMetadata);
nullPointerError.putAll(stockName, stockMetadata);
```

The `putAll` method will iterate over the `stockMetadata`  iterable and add the elements one by one into the `map`'s underlying list.

Comment: Thank you for your approach Dmitry! Actually i am in work, but i will take take a closer look on it later that day. Basically i wanted to copy lists which contain <String, String, String, String> to every <key>  in a ListValuedMap <key=String, value=List<String>> so that every <key> is connected with a List<String>. I expected to get several String values for each key.

Comment: Okay, i understand the context now, why it´s ListValuedMap<String, String> instead of ListValuedMap<String, List<String>>. List<E> is a subinterface of Iterable<T> and in the case of stockMetadata the return type T is String, so i can add a List <String> to the ListValuedMap via putAll which iterates over the List <E> until the end and adds every String one after one to the key.

Thank you again!